# Cannot update table by counting fields in related table

Tags: mysql, join

I'd like to update `followers` in `profile` table by counting the `followed_id` on `follow` table.

```
mysql> explain follow;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| followed_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| follower_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And

```
mysql> explain profile;
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| user_id        | int(10)       | NO   | MUL | 0                 |                |

| followers      | int(7)        | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| following      | int(7)        | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Here is the query that I came up with:

```
UPDATE profile A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id,COUNT(*) idcount FROM follow  GROUP BY id) as B
  ON B.id = A.user_id 
SET A.followers = B.idcount
```

But the query does not work as it should. It adds only `1` when profile has followers.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use a `left join` instead

Comment: It is not a good idea to store redundant data in the profile table. Get the followers by join whenever you need them

Comment: @juergend using `left join` I get `ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'followers' cannot be null
`, as not all profiles have followrs.

Comment: then use a where statement. WHERE followers IS NOT NULL

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff you are right, but to save some expensive joins we need to appeal to some de-normalization.

Comment: Then also use `SET A.followers = coalesce(B.idcount, 0)`

Comment: Joins are normally not expensive if you set the right indexes

Comment: Ich have up to 8 joins in my queries which reply in less then 100ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently counting the number of rows for each `id` value in `follow`, which is always going to be 1. What you need to do is count the number of `follower_id` values for each `followed_id`. Also, as @juergend pointed out, you should use a `LEFT JOIN` so that you can get 0 values for users with no followers. Change your query to this:

```
UPDATE profile A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT followed_id, COUNT(DISTINCT follower_id) AS idcount 
           FROM follow
           GROUP BY followed_id) as B ON B.followed_id = A.user_id 
SET A.followers = COALESCE(B.idcount, 0)
```

You can use a similar query to update `following`:

```
UPDATE profile A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT follower_id, COUNT(DISTINCT followed_id) AS idcount 
           FROM follow
           GROUP BY follower_id) as B ON B.follower_id = A.user_id 
SET A.following = COALESCE(B.idcount, 0)
```